# Clearing Cache In Glide- Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-glide

I was using picasso to display images and thereafter decided to switch to glide. Whenever, a user logs in through facebook, i use Glide to display the photo of the logged in user. I changed my photo in facebook, but Glide still displays the old image.

After researching, i come across the fact that Glide caches the image. This is how i tried to remove the cache so Glide could upload the new image. This is how i clear my cache

`Glide.With(comment).Load(user.PhotoUrl).DiskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.None).SkipMemoryCache(true).Into(message_profile);`

But it doesn't help. What else can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From Glide's [wiki](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation)

> In practice, the best way to invalidate a cache file is to change your
>   identifier when the content changes (url, uri, file path etc).

So one way is changing the url of the image

Other way is using `signature` while loading image.

```
.signature(new StringSignature(
System.currentTimeMillis() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
```

This code would update the cache daily. you can set any interval of update.

Ref : [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/using-glide-few-tips-to-be-a-pro-60f41e29d30a)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, altough like Nilesh said, the signature is probably enough.

```
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
    .Apply(RequestOptions.SkipMemoryCacheOf(true))
    .Apply(RequestOptions.DiskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.None))
    .Apply(RequestOptions.SignatureOf(new ObjectKey(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)));

Glide.With(this)
    .Load(imgUri)
    .Apply(requestOptions)
    .Into(_imageView);
```

You don't necessarily have to create a requestOptions variable, but that's up to you and probably the amount of options you use, like cropping etc.